# How to bridge rclpy with Python's asyncio?

Tags: python, ros2

In my opinion, the correct way of running ROS2 nodes inside a larger asynchronous Python application (e.g., an application built around asyncio) is not particularly obvious. I think a good solution should (i) not busy-wait the middleware and (ii) should handle cancellation properly.

I have had go at this and found a solution (see [my answer](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/24305/33281)) and would like to know if anyone else has a better solution or can see any flaws in my solution.

Comment: Could someone with more reputation create the following tags: python, rclpy, asynchronous

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code creates a bridge between `rclpy.spin` and an application built around Python's `asyncio`. The guard condition is used to interrupt `rmw_wait` and hence return early from `spin_once` (to handle the case where nothing else is happening). I am using Python 3.6, but I think the same principles apply to later versions of Python with the addition of some nicer APIs being available.

```py
import threading
import asyncio
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node

async def spin(node: Node):
    cancel = node.create_guard_condition(lambda: None)
    def _spin(node: Node,
              future: asyncio.Future,
              event_loop: asyncio.AbstractEventLoop):
        while not future.cancelled():
            rclpy.spin_once(node)
        if not future.cancelled():
            event_loop.call_soon_threadsafe(future.set_result, None)
    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    spin_task = event_loop.create_future()
    spin_thread = threading.Thread(target=_spin, args=(node, spin_task, event_loop))
    spin_thread.start()
    try:
        await spin_task
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        cancel.trigger()
    spin_thread.join()
    node.destroy_guard_condition(cancel)
```

This code can then be used, for example, like this:

```py
async def main():
    # create a node without any work to do
    node = Node('unused')

    # create tasks for spinning and sleeping
    spin_task = asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(spin(node))
    sleep_task = asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(asyncio.sleep(5.0))

    # concurrently execute both tasks
    await asyncio.wait([spin_task, sleep_task], return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)

    # cancel tasks
    if spin_task.cancel():
        await spin_task
    if sleep_task.cancel():
        await sleep_task

# run program
rclpy.init()
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
asyncio.get_event_loop().close()
rclpy.shutdown()
```

Comment: Nice! But isn't that a busy loop? Won't it clog the CPU?

Comment: Nope, the thread blocks at `rclpy.spin_once(node)` and only unblocks once there is something to do (e.g. a message being retrieved or the cancelled guard condition being triggered)

Comment: I integrated this in my code and added a print under the spin_once, and it prints all the time :-/

Comment: I am using quite similar code in my current project and I am pretty sure that should not be the case. Are you sure there are no messages being sent or received?

Comment: You are right. It does block. Silly me

Comment: I'm not sure how this works with a regular rclpy node with pubs and subs. Could you post a snippet showing this off in a setup that's a little bit more than just sleeping and spinning an 'unused' node?